# Regex Expression to match URLs

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following regex to detect URLS:

```
/(\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/ig
```

However, it doesn't detect urls such as `www.google.ca` and `tlk.tc/ApSE`. Is there an regex where I can detect these URLs? I am using javascript.

Comment: Try [this link](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+url+regex) (google: javascript url regex).

Comment: Important ftp connections can also be secure (`ftps`, `sftp`) and `file:` require three slashes `file:///` on windows

Comment: "www.google.ca" is not a URL, it's an FQDN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This expression does what you want. It is not a valid URL which this regexp is matching, but it fits your requirements:

```
/(\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/|\bwww\.[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])|([\S]+\.([a-z]{2,})+?\/[\S]+)/gi
```

Comment: this works except for http://www.google.ca where it counts it as two urls (according to a piece of code I've written). Why does it do this?

Comment: It requires a slash after the domain. Your requirement was: `www.google.ca and tlk.tc/ApSE`. Either the www. or the slash and at least one char is missing.

Comment: How would you change the expression so that once it detects http:// and then www comes right after, then that's one url instead of separating them into two?

Comment: Just move the first closing bracket (after `|file`) behind `www\.`. So the whole regex looks like this: `(\b(https?|ftp|file:\/\/|\bwww\.)[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])|([\S]+\.([a-z]{2,})+?\/[\S]+)`

Comment: And, was my regular expression helpful for you?

Comment: Yeah it was. Best answer here! Thanks Armin!

Comment: A url which isn't valid testhttp://www.google.ca doesn't pass using the above regex. I am not sure but I think you nee to put a ^$ somewhere. What would the regex look like.

Answer (score 3):

**Edit:**

Try this one:

```
((\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/)?[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]+\.[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|]+)
```

It makes the scheme optional, to support the two cases that you show in your example.

The IETF [RFC-2396](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt) for URLs gives the following regular expression *for parsing URLs*:

```
^(([^:/?#]+):)?(//([^/?#]*))?([^?#]*)(\?([^#]*))?(#(.*))?
```

which maps the capture groups to the following components:

```
scheme    = $2
authority = $4
path      = $5
query     = $7
fragment  = $9
```

Note that the examples you give, `www.google.ca` and `tlk.tc/ApSE` are not "valid" URLs, but I believe they'd be matched by the regex anyway.

Comment: I have tested this expression here: http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ and it doesn't work with any domain o.0

Comment: You're right... I misread the IETF doc. This regex is used for parsing URLs, not finding them. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Try `^(([^:/?\#]+):)?(//([^/?\#]*))?([^\?\#]*)(\?([^\#]*))?(\#(.*))?` at that website.

Comment: I am trying to match the url shortener like twitter so I want to detect URLs like twitter.